# JtextArea для вывода результата

Tags: java

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Как вывести данные на экран в поле jtextArea?
JtextArea описан в одном классе, данные для вывода получаются из другого класса. Результат кладется в String. Затем использую textArea.append(String), но сталкиваюсь с необходимостью чтобы jtextArea был static. Но в этом случае другая ошибка `cannot bind: field is static`

```
public class InputData extends JDialog {
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField loginTextField;
    private JPasswordField passwordPasswordField;
    private JComboBox comboBox1;
    private JButton загрузитьЛогButton;
    private JProgressBar progressBar1;
    private JComboBox comboBox2;
    private JTextField textField1;
    private JTextArea textArea1;
    static String[] selectedItem;
    static String selectedMethod;
    static String searchText;



public class FindErrorsInLog {

    /*Глобальные переменные*/
    static String resultText;

    /*Файл, с которым работаем, всегда !!!: homeDir + "\\Downloads\\SystemOut.log"*/

    /*Поиск ошибок*/
    public static void findErrors() {
        try {
            FileReader systemoutLogFR = new FileReader(DownloadFileFromRemoteServer.homeDir + "\\Downloads\\SystemOut.log");
            Scanner systemoutLogSC = new Scanner(systemoutLogFR);
            while (systemoutLogSC.hasNextLine()) {
                String solog = systemoutLogSC.nextLine();
                if (solog.contains(" E ") || solog.contains(" ERROR ")) {
                    resultText = (DownloadFileFromRemoteServer.SFTPHOST + " " + "Есть ошибки " + solog);                      /*Вывод на ЭФ*/
                    System.out.println(DownloadFileFromRemoteServer.SFTPHOST + " " + "Есть ошибки " + solog);                     /*Вывод в консоль*/
                }
            }
```

Comment: Код свой покажите.

Comment: Зачем у вас метод `findErrors` статический?

Comment: Потому что я вызываю его в другом методе другого класса

Comment: Нестатические методы прекрасно вызываются из других классов.

Comment: В моем случае получаю ошибку при компиляции nonstatic method cannot be referenced from a static content

Comment: Значит вы пытаетесь нестатический метод вызывать как статический.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Прошу пояснить. Я просто вызываю этот метод в лисенере при нажатии на кнопку на gui

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev И как это решит мою проблему?

Comment: 1) убираешь static из метода
2) `new FindErrorsInLog().findErrors();` // получишь вызов

Comment: Понятно. А как тогда вызвать textArea1 из метода findErrors, чтобы туда вывелась информация?